# Iterate through list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create a condition to check every element in java List. 
I have elements that return a boolean value.
In the code isFieldTagStart return false or true. My mean goal is every element in the List has to be start with the true value and be followed with false value. Thus one true after one false than again one true and again false.

```
for (AbstractField field : form.getFields()) {
    if (field instanceof FieldSetTag) {
        FieldSetTag fieldsetTag = (FieldSetTag)field;                       
        if (fieldsetTag.isFieldSetTagStart()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is so far i can think about the code. Can please somebody help me to finish the code?

Comment: Can you provide a table detailing the values you want? See the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)